# How can I debug this binary (which I suspect does encryption)?

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis, cryptography

I have a snippet of binary code which performs some encryption algorithm (most likely modified RC4). I have four variables associated with the encryption (seed_key_arg [1-3] and a seed_key) and encrypted output data. Most likely I have some cleartext as well.

I have never disassembled something before, so it is hard for me to begin. Is there a way for me to run the program with the material that I have, and try to decrypt the data? Since I am assuming that it is a stream cipher, the algorithm shoudl be the same for decrypting it...

Here is the output from Radare2 to show what I'm dealing with:

```
/ (fcn) fcn.00000000 380
|   fcn.00000000 (int arg_8h, int arg_ch, int arg_10h, int arg_14h);
|           ; var int local_10ch @ rbp-0x10c
|           ; var int local_8h @ rbp-0x8
|           ; var int local_4h @ rbp-0x4
|           ; arg int arg_8h @ rbp+0x8
|           ; arg int arg_ch @ rbp+0xc
|           ; arg int arg_10h @ rbp+0x10
|           ; arg int arg_14h @ rbp+0x14
|           0x00000000      89e5           mov ebp, esp
|           0x00000002      81ec14010000   sub esp, 0x114
|           0x00000008      8b4514         mov eax, dword [rbp + arg_14h] ; [0x14:4]=0x69007400
|           0x0000000b      89c1           mov ecx, eax
|           0x0000000d      8d95f4feffff   lea edx, dword [rbp - local_10ch]
|           0x00000013      b800740069     mov eax, 0x69007400
|           0x00000018      0d73007200     or eax, 0x720073
|           0x0000001d      8902           mov dword [rdx], eax
|           0x0000001f      83c204         add edx, 4
|           0x00000022      b800677300     mov eax, 0x736700
|           0x00000027      356e000034     xor eax, 0x3400006e
|           0x0000002c      8902           mov dword [rdx], eax
|           0x0000002e      83c204         add edx, 4
|           0x00000031      b899939e98     mov eax, 0x989e9399
|           0x00000036      f7d0           not eax
|           0x00000038      8902           mov dword [rdx], eax
|           0x0000003a      31c0           xor eax, eax
|           0x0000003c      81c2fc000000   add edx, 0xfc
|           0x00000042      8902           mov dword [rdx], eax
|       ,=< 0x00000044      eb0d           jmp 0x53
|      .--> 0x00000046      8b02           mov eax, dword [rdx]
|      ||   0x00000048      888c05f4feff.  mov byte [rbp + rax - 0x10c], cl
|      ||   0x0000004f      40418902       mov dword [r10], eax
|      ||   ; JMP XREF from 0x00000044 (fcn.00000000)
|      |`-> 0x00000053      813aff000000   cmp dword [rdx], 0xff       ; [0xff:4]=0xb60ff845 ; 255
|      `==< 0x00000059      76eb           jbe 0x46
|           0x0000005b      31c0           xor eax, eax
|           0x0000005d      8902           mov dword [rdx], eax
|           0x0000005f      83ea04         sub edx, 4
|           0x00000062      8902           mov dword [rdx], eax
|           0x00000064      53             push rbx
|           0x00000065      89d3           mov ebx, edx
|       ,=< 0x00000067      eb5f           jmp 0xc8
|      .--> 0x00000069      8b03           mov eax, dword [rbx]
|      ||   0x0000006b      0fb68405f4fe.  movzx eax, byte [rbp + rax - 0x10c]
|      ||   0x00000073      0fb6c0         movzx eax, al
|      ||   0x00000076      89c2           mov edx, eax
|      ||   0x00000078      0355f8         add edx, dword [rbp - local_8h]
|      ||   0x0000007b      8b03           mov eax, dword [rbx]
|      ||   0x0000007d      83e00f         and eax, 0xf
|      ||   0x00000080      03450c         add eax, dword [rbp + arg_ch]
|      ||   0x00000083      0fb600         movzx eax, byte [rax]
|      ||   0x00000086      0fb6c0         movzx eax, al
|      ||   0x00000089      8d0402         lea eax, dword [rdx + rax]
|      ||   0x0000008c      25ff000000     and eax, 0xff
|      ||   0x00000091      8945f8         mov dword [rbp - local_8h], eax
|      ||   0x00000094      8b03           mov eax, dword [rbx]
|      ||   0x00000096      0fb68405f4fe.  movzx eax, byte [rbp + rax - 0x10c]
|      ||   0x0000009e      0fb6c0         movzx eax, al
|      ||   0x000000a1      8945fc         mov dword [rbp - local_4h], eax
|      ||   0x000000a4      8b13           mov edx, dword [rbx]
|      ||   0x000000a6      8b45f8         mov eax, dword [rbp - local_8h]
|      ||   0x000000a9      0fb68405f4fe.  movzx eax, byte [rbp + rax - 0x10c]
|      ||   0x000000b1      888415f4feff.  mov byte [rbp + rdx - 0x10c], al
|      ||   0x000000b8      8b55f8         mov edx, dword [rbp - local_8h]
|      ||   0x000000bb      8b45fc         mov eax, dword [rbp - local_4h]
|      ||   0x000000be      888415f4feff.  mov byte [rbp + rdx - 0x10c], al
|      ||   0x000000c5      830301         add dword [rbx], 1
|      ||   ; JMP XREF from 0x00000067 (fcn.00000000)
|      |`-> 0x000000c8      813bff000000   cmp dword [rbx], 0xff       ; [0xff:4]=0xb60ff845 ; 255
|      `==< 0x000000ce      7699           jbe 0x69
|           0x000000d0      31c0           xor eax, eax
|           0x000000d2      8903           mov dword [rbx], eax
|           0x000000d4      83c304         add ebx, 4
|           0x000000d7      8903           mov dword [rbx], eax
|           0x000000d9      83eb04         sub ebx, 4
|       ,=< 0x000000dc      e98d000000     jmp 0x16e
|      .--> 0x000000e1      830301         add dword [rbx], 1
|      ||   0x000000e4      8b03           mov eax, dword [rbx]
|      ||   0x000000e6      25ff000000     and eax, 0xff
|      ||   0x000000eb      0fb68405f4fe.  movzx eax, byte [rbp + rax - 0x10c]
|      ||   0x000000f3      0fb6c0         movzx eax, al
|      ||   0x000000f6      0345f8         add eax, dword [rbp - local_8h]
|      ||   0x000000f9      25ff000000     and eax, 0xff
|      ||   0x000000fe      8945f8         mov dword [rbp - local_8h], eax
|      ||   0x00000101      0fb68405f4fe.  movzx eax, byte [rbp + rax - 0x10c]
|      ||   0x00000109      0fb6c0         movzx eax, al
|      ||   0x0000010c      8945fc         mov dword [rbp - local_4h], eax
|      ||   0x0000010f      8b55f8         mov edx, dword [rbp - local_8h]
|      ||   0x00000112      8b03           mov eax, dword [rbx]
|      ||   0x00000114      25ff000000     and eax, 0xff
|      ||   0x00000119      0fb68405f4fe.  movzx eax, byte [rbp + rax - 0x10c]
|      ||   0x00000121      888415f4feff.  mov byte [rbp + rdx - 0x10c], al
|      ||   0x00000128      8b03           mov eax, dword [rbx]
|      ||   0x0000012a      0fb6d0         movzx edx, al
|      ||   0x0000012d      8b45fc         mov eax, dword [rbp - local_4h]
|      ||   0x00000130      888415f4feff.  mov byte [rbp + rdx - 0x10c], al
|      ||   0x00000137      8b03           mov eax, dword [rbx]
|      ||   0x00000139      83e801         sub eax, 1
|      ||   0x0000013c      89c1           mov ecx, eax
|      ||   0x0000013e      034d08         add ecx, dword [rbp + arg_8h]
|      ||   0x00000141      8b03           mov eax, dword [rbx]
|      ||   0x00000143      83e801         sub eax, 1
|      ||   0x00000146      034508         add eax, dword [rbp + arg_8h]
|      ||   0x00000149      0fb610         movzx edx, byte [rax]
|      ||   0x0000014c      8b45f8         mov eax, dword [rbp - local_8h]
|      ||   0x0000014f      0fb68405f4fe.  movzx eax, byte [rbp + rax - 0x10c]
|      ||   0x00000157      0fb6c0         movzx eax, al
|      ||   0x0000015a      0345fc         add eax, dword [rbp - local_4h]
|      ||   0x0000015d      25ff000000     and eax, 0xff
|      ||   0x00000162      0fb68405f4fe.  movzx eax, byte [rbp + rax - 0x10c]
|      ||   0x0000016a      31d0           xor eax, edx
|      ||   0x0000016c      8801           mov byte [rcx], al
|      ||   ; JMP XREF from 0x000000dc (fcn.00000000)
|      |`-> 0x0000016e      8b03           mov eax, dword [rbx]
|      |    0x00000170      3b4510         cmp eax, dword [rbp + arg_10h] ; [0x10:4]=0xb8fffffe
|      `==< 0x00000173      0f8268ffffff   jb 0xe1
|           0x00000179      5b             pop rbx
|           0x0000017a      c9             leave
\           0x0000017b      c3             ret
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the binary file, for sure you can debug it. I suggest you to use gdb for debug it.

```
$ gdb your_program
(gdb) b main
(gdb) r
```

I suggest you to insert some breakpoint in the fuctions that you want to analyze, and then follow them (`nexti/stepi`)

You could try also to use `strace/ltrace` to understend better the context

Look at this link http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html

Comment: I can't run the file since it's not executable by itself. It probably acts as a plug-in.

Comment: It is a shared library (.so)?

Comment: No, I just have a hexdump of the program. The disassembled printout above shows all the info I have.

Comment: the function seems to have no calls or jumps outside rip the opcodes convert to binary embed in a wrapper and try calling it with inputs and tesy radare output appears to be cutting off the opcodes after certain length you may need to improvise  possibly add 0xffff in place of . dots in the disaasembled outpur